# How to add Display None property to Img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi i need to add display none to **img** tag ....

what i have tried so far...

```
 $('.droppedFields .droppedField').children('img').attr('style', 'display:none');
```

but it is not working! Any help

```
<div class="span5 well droppedFields ui-droppable ui-sortable">
    <div class="draggableField ui-draggable droppedField" id="CTRL-DIV-1001">
        <img src="CntrlImages/form-title-icon.gif">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Form Title" id="Header-text" class="ctrl-emailbox headerText" disabled="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: should work. is element loaded when script is fired??

Comment: let me paste my whole script

Comment: Just pasted your code, it works : https://jsfiddle.net/q2dc5tau/1/

Comment: This works:  $('.droppedField img').hide();

Comment: @VincentG My code ,, not working but please have a look

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: @Roberto , ,works cool , but i have two types of elements, on the left side form control is hidden with the Image , when i clicked over this i need this to be append on the right hand side div that is having class.. (droppedFields) ... So i want to find this within (droppedFields) class and then droppedField annd then img tag.. and hide this image on right hand side

Comment: @VincentG my fiddle is not working ... but you can have a look over the whole code

Comment: @seriouscoder In this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q2dc5tau/1/ 
I just add your code with jQuery library and it's already working,

Comment: @VincentG can we discuss via chat,, it will help me to make u understand better

Comment: @seriouscoder yes if you want, I'm on http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have less reputation to talk in chat , please up vote my question to make me eligible

Comment: https://discord.gg/0wXC2NZ9BOP30zoR

Comment: I am there pelase come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css to img tag

```
  .draggableField img {
    display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$('.droppedFields .droppedField').children('img').css("display","none");
```